# rewriting group by in subselect

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 queries and both the queries are showing different results when moving the where clause in inner select query.

```
select destination_number, count(*) as cnt from (
select caller_id_number as caller_id_number, destination_number as destination_number 
from Final1  where start_stamp > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and start_stamp < '2013-01-26 00:00:00' 
group by caller_id_number, destination_number) 
where destination_number = '1234' 
group by  destination_number
```

count result: 294636

```
select destination_number, count(*) as cnt from (
select caller_id_number as caller_id_number, destination_number as destination_number 
from Final1  where destination_number = '1234' and start_stamp > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and start_stamp < '2013-01-26 00:00:00' 
group by caller_id_number, destination_number) 
group by  destination_number
```

count result: 310627

I will like to know why does the count change and which query is correct.

Comment: I'm investigating. At first glance this seems surprising that you'd get different results for the two queries. Are these the exact queries you ran? If not, and you don't want to post the real queries, can you give the job ids of the queries?

Comment: I dropped the table cdrFinal1 and recreated. Now I can not reproduce the bug. This must be because the data was not populated correctly. I do not see the query ID when I run the query from interface.